# How to unmod CDTV keyboard

Tags: keyboards, amiga-cdtv, amiga-cd32

I have a CDTV keyboard that someone modded to work with CD32. There are no bridges or extra components on the board, however [pinout](http://l8r.net/technical/t-keyboard.shtml) was changed at the board - wire connector and I'm not sure how to swap it back?

[image: current pinouts]

Comment: Presumably the cable's wiring was modified either at the board end or at the plug end.  Can you add photos of both ends of the cable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CD32 pinout [is the similar to the Amiga 4000](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Commodore_Amiga#Amiga_4000_.28T.29) (*1), so maybe have a look at [this page](http://www.rockus.at/Amiga/cdtv2a4000.html) comparing it to the CDTV. From there it should be easy to work back.

Pinout for all Amiga series machines with detached keyboards is:

```
Pin | A1000 | A2/3000 | CDTV  | A4000 | CD32
----+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------
 1  | +5V   | CLOCK   | GND   | DATA  | DATA
 2  | CLOCK | DATA    | DATA  | n/c   | TxD
 3  | DATA  | n/c     | CLOCK | GND   | GND
 4  | GND   | GND     | +5V   | +5V   | +5V
 5  |       | +5V     | SENSE | CLOCK | CLOCK
 6  |       |         |       | n/c   | RxD
```

(Names Unified. Commodore uses different names for each machine)

**CAVEAT: the following are deductions made from the picture (and above table) under the assumptions that the claims made in the question as well as the assignment markings on the picture are valid.**

Seen on the picture the sequence on the PCB (left to right) and their connection to Mini-Din are:

1. Red
2. White
3. Yellow
4. Orange

Assuming the assignments in the picture are checked, and the plug being wired for A4000/CD32, then using the pin assignment from the table reveals the pinout of the white connector as:

1. DATA (Red)
2. CLOCK (White)
3. +5V (Yellow)
4. GND (Orange)

Thus, to make it a CDTV cabling again the wires on the white connector need to be reordered (left to right) like this:

1. Orange
2. Yellow
3. White
4. Red

Now isn't that funny? As if the Connector is simply turned upside down. Maybe a result due layout or a classic sequence inversion error. Have you checked if the connector can be turned?

Which leaves me wondering about the SENSE signal, which should be as well connected. At least to ground, which would be the red wire. Otherwise it's possible that the cable hasn't been modified, but rather replaced ... not sure.

*Again, all of this is just guesswork from my table and the picture shown, taking the questions claims as true.*

---

*1 - The CD32 also carries a serial interface here.

Comment: it's also the same as for the Amiga 2000.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre AFAIK not. the A2000/3000 uses a different connector, as well as a different pinout. See the table ... of course, as always, I might be wrong :)

Comment: you're right. A2000 keyboard probably using big DIN connector. Not the same connector but probably works with an adaptator

Comment: BINGO! Many thanks, bit makes me wonder what is this _KBSE (Keyboard Sense). Not connected, but no issue with keyboard whatsoever.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes, AFAIK all their protocols are compatible (though, not all keyboards), so all can be made working using an adaptor.